# VSCODE - vscodevim plugin incremental search keybindings

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

When using VSCODE vscodevim plugin forward slash / puts you in incremental search mode -

What is the keybinding to put the cursor on the current search "view"? when i escape from incremental search mode it moves off the search result view in the file and puts the cursor back at the original position that the cursor was in when the / key was first pressed unlike regular vim which makes incremental search almost useless.

Comment: You should probably ask your question on the [VSCodeVim github issues page](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues).

Answer (score 0):

In VSCodeVim, like in Vim, pressing `<Esc>` in an incremental search will return the cursor position to where you started the search. Also like Vim, pressing `<Enter>` will move the cursor to where the match was found.